# VBA: passing variables to sub() with custom type

Tags: arrays, vba, parameter-passing, subroutine, custom-data-type

I am playing with calling a sub() but keep getting "User-defined type not defined" error. Unable to figure out after trying different ways of declaring variables as array. Would appreciate any guidance on this:

```
Public Type Whatever
    ppp As String
    qqq As Long
    rrr As Single
End Type




Sub isthisworking()
 Dim thisis() As Whatever
 Dim i As Long
 Dim athing As Long

 For i = 0 To 5
    With thisis(i)
        .ppp = i & "p"
        .qqq = i * 2
        .rrr = i ^ 3
    End With

 athing = 20

 beingcalled thisis(), athing

End Sub



Public Sub beingcalled(ByRef thisis() As Whatever, athing As Long)

 Dim cycles As Long

 cycles = UBound(thisis)

 For i = 0 To cycles - 1
    With thisis(i)
        Debug.Print i & ": " & .ppp & "," & .qqq & "," & .rrr
    End With
 Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Once I dimension `thisis` properly, add `Next` to your for-loop, and change the call `beingcalled thisis(), athing` to `beingcalled thisis, athing`, it works with no problem.

Comment: Thanks @Johncoleman. Clearly not on top of dimensioning yet. Or cut and paste skills either!

Comment: When do you need to actually use the CALL statement? And why is is that with calling functions you need to use somefunction(var1, var2,....) but for sub the parentheses are omitted? Is there ever a need for them?

Comment: @user110084 try the code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `For i = 0 To 5` is missing the closing `Next i` statement.

You need to `Redim` the size of your `thisis()` array:

```
ReDim thisis(o To 5)
```

the whole "**isthisworking**" Sub:

```
Sub isthisworking()

Dim thisis() As Whatever
Dim i As Long
Dim athing As Long

ReDim thisis(o To 5)

For i = 0 To 5
   With thisis(i)
       .ppp = i & "p"
       .qqq = i * 2
       .rrr = i ^ 3
   End With
Next i

athing = 20

beingcalled thisis(), athing    
' you can pass also thisis (without the brackets) gives the same result

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @ShaiRado. Yes, I somehow skipped the NEXT line when copying and pasting. I also had problems with custom type not being recognised until I deleted the module and inserted a new one.

I did not know that you could call a sub without () like beingcalled(thesies(), athing). I had always preceded it with CALL as well. Can I do the same format with functions?

Comment: @ShaiRodo, the Redim var(o to 5), does the "o" make it the same is preserve? Not seen that documented

Comment: Calling functions can be different, especially if the function returns an arguement, Redim Preserve is a different method than Redim

Comment: Sorry to be ignorant about these @ShaiRado. What is the difference between Redim (o to 5) and Redim(5)? And is there a reason for actually using the CALL statement or use the sub name without CALL?

Comment: you can read about the difference in `Redim` and `Redim Preserve` here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx

Comment: So the 4th line should be Redim(0 to 5) not Redim(o to 5). The confusion was not over Redim and Redim Preserve, but (0 to 5) vs (o to 5).

Comment: @user110084 yes, that's a Zero :)